# Cannot access to phpmyadmin when using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker on my project and I set up my docker-compose file like this:

```
    db_service:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

when I login to phpmyadmin on http://localhost:8082 It show an erro

> mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name does not resolve

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try link, depends and env variable PMA_HOST

> db_service:
>
> ```
>  container_name: database
>  image: mysql:latest
>  ports:
>    - "3306:3306"
>  environment:
>    - MYSQL_USER=root
>    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
>    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
>    - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database
>  phpmyadmin:
>
>  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
>  container_name: phpmyadmin 
>    depends_on:
>    - database
>  links:
>    - database
>  ports:
>    - "8082:80"
> ```
>
> environment:
>
> ```
>    - MYSQL_USER=root
>    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
>    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
>    - PMA_HOST=database
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You need to link the two containers and provide login credentials for PHPMyAdmin so it can connect to the MySQL instance. Try the following:

```
version: '3.2'
    services:
    db_service:
        container_name: database
        image: mysql:latest
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_USER=root
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
          - db_service:mysql
        ports:
          - 8082:80
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
```

Comment: I already try to link the containers but still got mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve error.

Comment: I gave it a try and had a little issue in the docker-compose. I updated my answer with how it works.